# Alternative for Facebook Export API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a data pipeline for our Facebook app events data. Is there any alternative solution for getting the facebook export data as it is deprecated and will stop working from Aug 1st 2018?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export

`The Export API is deprecated and will stop working on August 1st 2018.`

Comment: Apparently looks like there is no way we can export the event data that belongs to our app from facebook. Well done facebook!

Comment: you got any closure on this ?

Comment: After the cambridge analytica scandal, the export API was deprecated & facebook partnered with 3rd party tracking solutions to get the app events data which means, we need to pay more :-)

Comment: haha, Branch it is then !!